# Using this.transitionTo to change query params gives error

Tags: javascript, ember.js, typeerror

Using pretty much copy paste from Ember.js docs

```
App.CresShowResultController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
queryParams: ['county'],
county: null,

   actions: {
       displayQueryData: function(){
           this.transitionTo({queryParams: {county: 'someCounty'}});
       },
   },

});
```

The action is called from another controller after a form is analysed.
I get an error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Here is the route as well.

```
App.CresShowResultRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function(){
       this.render('showResult');
    }
});
```

**SideQuestion:** How can I use transitionTo to change URL parameters straight from another controller without using the action "displayUseryData" as middleman function?

EDIT: Added my Router.map to specify:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('cres', function() {
    this.route('showResult');
  });

  this.resource('about');
  this.resource('posts', function() {
    //child route posted inside the parent
    this.resource('post', { path: ':post_id'});
  });
});
```

Like always, thank you for any helping comments!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
App.CresShowResultController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
queryParams: ['county'],
county: null,

   actions: {
       displayQueryData: function(){
           this.transitionTo({queryParams: {county: 'someCounty'}});
       }.bind(this),
   },
});
```

I think that "this" in the displayQueryData function is a window reference.

Comment: Thanks but did not work. Also changed this.transitionTo to this.transitionToRoute but none of the combinations worked.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you reference above, just updating the queryParam itself will have the effect you are looking for.

In the route, you can define if these queryParams will replace the url, or if it will refresh the model.

Use the transitionToRoute, when you wish to switch to a different route, or different model.

```
App.CresShowResultController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
queryParams: ['county'],
county: null,

   actions: {
       displayQueryData: function(){
           this.set('county', 'someCounty');
           // this.transitionTo({queryParams: {county: 'someCounty'}});
       },
   },

});
```